# How do I heal my survivors?

Tags: tinker-island

I know if they completely run out of health, they rest for a while and then get their health back. But is there any way for me to heal them before that point? Or am I stuck just waiting til they run out completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can craft health potions to heal your islanders.  Health potions are crafted from the "Items" menu and when done, will appear on the left hand card deck.  Simply drag and drop an islander onto the card and they use the potion.